# When do Meteor method callbacks fire?

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback

My question is very simple: given a Meteor method that is loaded on both, server and client, if you call this method on / from the client and provide a callback when does this callback fire?

1. When the frontend simulation is completed?
2. When the backend *and* frontend calls are completed?

The [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-call) just say:

> Meteor tracks the database updates performed as part of a method call, and waits to invoke the client-side callback until all of those updates have been sent to the client.

This imho does not make clear whether it is waiting for the server side updates or client side simulated updates. If it is always waiting for the server side, this basically breaks the "latency compensation" at that point as you cannot call methods on / from the client other than async style as you have no fibers.

Comment: If you provide a callback, it will be called once the server has completed execution of the method. I agree the docs could me more clear.

Comment: It's more than just that. According to the docs, there's the stub run and server call and , server run and response, then cache comparison and overwrite and eventually the callback.

Comment: @MasterAM : can you explain how the things you mention contradict the answer that the callback fires if and only if the server side has completed and all the changes have been transferred to the client?

Comment: I was referring to the answer to the question that this one is marked as a duplicate of and to David's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man the language around this couldn't be any more confusing. I believe that it will only be called once, after the server has finished.

From the Meteor docs.

> Meteor tracks the database writes performed by methods, both on the client and the server, and does not invoke asyncCallback until all of the server's writes replace the stub's writes in the local cache. In some cases, there can be a lag between the method's return value being available and the writes being visible

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please provide a link to the source?

Comment: @BM it's the last paragraph of [this section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) right before the `apply` section.